# A nice proof of the identity $\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}(-1)^i\binom{n+i}{l}\binom{l+1}{i}=0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The identity $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}=0$$
has a nice proof: notice that the LHS equals $(1-1)^n$.

Today, I came across the identity
$$\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}(-1)^i\binom{n+i}{l}\binom{l+1}{i}=0$$

For instance, $$\binom{n}{2}-3\binom{n+1}{2}+3\binom{n+2}{2}-\binom{n+3}{2}=0$$.

Is there a proof of this identity in a similar vein?

Comment: The relation becomes obvious once you see $u\to\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}(-1)^i\binom{l+1}{i} u_i$ as equivalent (up to sign) to the forward difference operator of order $l+1$, and $\binom{n+i}{l}$ is a polynomial in $i$ of degree $l$. Then the $(l+1)$-difference of a polynomial of degree $l$ is zero. Precisely, the forward difference operator is defined by $\Delta (u)(i)=u_{i+1}-u_i$ and $\Delta^k u=\Delta(\Delta^{k-1}u)$. And if $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, $\Delta P$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thanks, got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a technique using the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^i\binom{n+i}{l}\binom{l+1}{i}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{i}(-1)^i[z^l](1+z)^{n+i}\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^l](1+z)^n\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{i}(-1)^i(1+z)^i\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^l](1+z)^n(1-(1+z))^{l+1}\\
> &=[z^l](1+z)^n(-z)^{l+1}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator as in (1).
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (4) we see that each term with $z$ has an exponent greater than $l$.

Comment: This is closest to the spirit of the question so I will accept this answer. Thank you!

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez: Many thanks for accepting my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just fleshing out Jean-Claude Arbaut's answer for my own sake:

Let $\Delta$ be the operator that takes $u(x)\mapsto u(x+1)-u(x)$. Then, inductively:

$$\Delta^l (u)(x)=\Delta^{l-1}(u)(x+1)-\Delta^{l-1}(u)(x)$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^l(-1)^i\binom{l}{i}u(x+1+i)-\sum_{i=0}^l(-1)^i\binom{l}{i}u(x+i)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{l+1}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{l}{i-1}u(x+i)-\sum_{i=0}^l(-1)^i\binom{l}{i}u(x+i)$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{l+1}{i}u(x+i)$$

Now set $u(x)=\binom{x}{l}$. This has degree $l$ so
$$0=\Delta^l(u)(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{l+1}{i}\binom{x+i}{l}$$

which is what I wanted, for $x=n$.

Comment: It should be $(-1)^{i+l+1}$ instead of $(-1)^{i-1}$ (we want the coefficient of $u(x+l+1)$ to be positive. That's why I wrote "up to sign" in my comment. But apart from that, you got it. You may also have a look at the [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I was hoping that the proof would be easy to modify for a $q$-analog of the identity, but I’m not sure that the $q$-difference operator $u\mapsto u(qx)-u(x)$ does what I would like it to do. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative using combinatorial argument.

**Set Up**

$n$ students and $l+1$ teachers are going to an amusement park. The park's official is eccentric and decides to limit the number of teachers who can enter to $i$. However, $l$ of those who enter the park get free beverages. The number of possibilities for a given $i$ is given by (almost) the summand:

$$
\binom{l+1}{i}\binom{n+i}{l}
$$

The LHS is then simply the difference in number of possibilities in which even or odd number of teachers enter the park:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}\left(-1\right)^{i}\binom{l+1}{i}\binom{n+i}{l}
$$

**Alternative Counting**

The park official can choose $l$ out of $n+l+1$ people who get free beverages. Teachers who get free beverages can enter the park. Some teachers who don't get free beverages can also enter the park.

Since only $l$ free beverages are available, there is at least a teacher who does not get free beverage, i.e. this is a non-empty set. It is well-known that a non-empty set has as many odd subset as even subset. Therefore, there are equal number of possibilities in which even number / odd number of teachers enter the park.

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{l+1}\left(-1\right)^{i}\binom{l+1}{i}\binom{n+i}{l}=0
$$

**Generalization**

Using the same argument, the following holds for any positive integer $m$:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{l+m}\left(-1\right)^{i}\binom{l+m}{i}\binom{n+i}{l}=0
$$